# How to make TableEntity serialize non-public properties?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, serialization, azure-table-storage

Azure Table Storage has some frustrating limitations like inability to handle `decimal` data type so I have to do this:

```
public class MyEntity : TableEntity {
        [IgnoreProperty]
        public decimal ListPrice
        {
            get => decimal.Parse(this.ListPrice_, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            set => this.ListPrice_ = value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        public string ListPrice_ { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously I don't want `ListPrice_` to be `public` but `private` members are seem to be ignored by the SDK. Is there any easy trick to make it serialize non-public members (without reflection)?

Comment: private members are private. Nothing outside of the class has any visibility of them, so no you can't *serialize non-public members (without reflection)*

Comment: I believe that's not how it supposed to work, it's serialization dependent. For example, if I use `DataContractSerializer` I can put `[DataMember]` on any private member and it will be handled just OK. We, as developers, should have full control on serialization of our data structures, shouldn't we?

Comment: DataContractSerializer uses reflection...In fact all serialisers use reflection

Comment: I don't get the point. Almost any serializer known to me allows to handle non-public members, if not by default but with overrides (either attribute or code based). I don't care if they use reflection or not internally I don't want it in my user code (if I wanted it I'd just override `WriteEntity()`/`ReadEntity()` and not bother the community) . The question is I don't know how the SDK handles serialization and if it allows to override the default behavior or not. I'd be happy to know if there is an option flag or equivalent of `[DataMember]` in the SDK I can decorate my members with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any attribute that can be used to serialize a non-public property of [TableEntity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableentity?view=azure-dotnet), but you can override [ReadEntity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.itableentity.readentity.aspx) and [WriteEntity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.itableentity.writeentity.aspx) methods of interface [ITableEntity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.itableentity.aspx) to customize your own property serialization.

```
public class MyEntity : TableEntity
{
    [IgnoreProperty]
    public decimal ListPrice
    {
        get => decimal.Parse(this.ListPrice_, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        set => this.ListPrice_ = value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    private string ListPrice_ { get; set; }

    public override void ReadEntity(IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> properties, OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        this.ListPrice_ = properties[nameof(ListPrice)].StringValue;
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> WriteEntity(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        var properties = new Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>();
        properties.Add(nameof(ListPrice), new EntityProperty(this.ListPrice_));
        return properties;
    }
}
```